# OCaml Cmdliner non-standard parameters

Tags: ocaml

I'm making an OCaml compiler front-end with Cmdliner, and I want to copy some of the behavior of Clang, such as the "-emit-llvm" option.  The code I've got, at present is:

```
(* Whether to generate LLVM (IR or bitcode) output. *)
let llvm =
  let doc = "In conjunction with -S or -c, generate LLVM output instead of
             native output.  For an object file, this means LLVM bitcode (.bc)
             will be generated, and for assembly it will be LLVM IR (.ll)."
  in
  let emit_llvm = Arg.info ["emit-llvm"] ~doc in
  Arg.(value & flag emit_llvm)
```

This creates the option "--emit-llvm" with 2 leading dashes, but it isn't clear how to do it with just 1.  Is this possible?

Comment: I think Cmdliner uses single dashes for short options consisting only of one character and double dashes for long options. So it is probably not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Cmdliner` can parse short flag groups (à la tar `-xvf`, see the end of [this section](http://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner#optargs)) this would become too ambiguous. Besides `Cmdliner`, following GNU's [conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html), does indeed mandate two dashes for long options.

What you can do however is to take your `Sys.argv` and patch a selection of single dash options you might recognise by pre-prending them with a single dash before giving the result explictitely to [`Term.eval`](http://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner.Term.html#VALeval) via the optional `argv` argument.

Comment: That's what I'll do.  Good call.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner.Arg.html#VALinfo), strings of length 1 map to short options (with a single dash), and others to long options (with two dashes). So as of `cmdliner.1.0.2`, this is not possible.